# How to use switch with more than one variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, switch-statement

I'm using Yahoo Weather and there are about 47 weather conditions from 0 to 47 each number represents the condition of the weather.

I want to get the condition for 4 days , today and the next 3 days so there will be a very long code of switch statements if I use a switch statement for each.

My code now for today condition:

```
var src = ""; //This variable will contain an icon that represents the weather condition.

switch(todayCondition){ //todayCondition is today condition it's in the range [0-47]

    case "0":
        src = 'storm.svg';
    break;
    ........
    ........
    case  "47":
        src = 'rain.svg';
    break;

}

document.getElementById('todayWeatherIcon').src = src;
```

The html:

```
 <img id = 'todayWeatherIcon' />
```

There are 3 other variables for the next 3 days conditions that will be from 0-47 too and will have the same icons depending on the number.

How to do the same thing for the other 3 variables without repeating the same code?

Comment: Are all your icons named `"condition<some number>Img.png"`? If so, why not get rid of the switch completely and just do `src = "condition" + todayCondition + "Img.png";`? Then repeat that for each day.

Comment: Sorry , It seems that you miss understand me and I didn't explain it well , The icons names are not "condition" + todayCondition + "Img.png"; , It's just an indication , The icons are like cloudy.svg , rain.svg , ... etc

Comment: I will edit the question

Comment: @peter, but if your "condition" always generates ints from `0..47`, you can use `var src = arrayOfIconNames[todayCondition];`

Answer (score 2):

there is no need for multiple switch statement, since you have a fixed file name with each weather condition number in the filename you could just do this

```
var src = "";
// concatenate todayCondition with the rest of the file name
src = "condition" + todayCondition + "Img.png";

document.getElementById('todayWeatherIcon').src = src;
```

**Note**: You should only do this if you know the names of the file won't change in the nearest future

Comment: Sorry , It seems that you miss understand me and I didn't explain it well , The icons names are not "condition" + todayCondition + "Img.png"; , It's just an indication , The icons are like cloudy.svg , rain.svg , ... etc

Comment: it's either you use the switch statement, or you use arrays and set their index to the possible weather values just as @Brettc specified.

Answer (score 1):

You could just set the condition like so

`src = 'condition'+todayCondition+'Img.png';
document.getElementById('todayWeatherIcon').src = src;`

Comment: Sorry , It seems that you miss understand me and I didn't explain it well , The icons names are not "condition" + todayCondition + "Img.png"; , It's just an indication , The icons are like cloudy.svg , rain.svg , ... etc

Comment: Could you put your conditions in an array and then just call the array location? `arry[4] = "cloudy.png", arry[5]="sunny.png"...`

Answer (score 0):

You should simply use a function :

```
function getIcon(weatherCondition) 
{
    var src = ""; //This variable will contain an icon that represents the weather condition.
    switch(weatherCondition){ //weatherCondition is the weather condition it's in the range [0-47]
        case "0":
            src = 'storm.svg';
            break;
        ........
        ........
        case  "47":
            src = 'rain.svg';
            break;
    }
    return src;
}

var day1Condition = getIcon(todayCondition);
var day2Condition = getIcon(tomorrowCondition);
...
document.getElementById('todayWeatherIcon').src = day1Condition;
document.getElementById('tomorrowWeatherIcon').src = day2Condition;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If the image names are all different then you can best use an array of strings, like this:

```js
var images = ["cloudy.svg", "sunny.svg", "rainy.svg"];

// Arrays are designed to work with numeric index values:
console.log(images[0]);
console.log(images[1]);
console.log(images[2]);
console.log("--------------")

// Javascript also accepts "numeric strings" as array index values:
console.log(images["0"]);
console.log(images["2"]);
console.log("--------------")

// Or using a variable, this is the closest to what you need to do:
var todayCondition = "1";
var src = images[todayCondition];
console.log(src);
```